# Python solutions

Tags: python, string, char

I am trying to delete a character one at a time up until the equal sign in a string (equation) in this case.

```
   def solutions(expression):
        positionOfEqualSign = expression.find("=")
        for i in range(0, len(expression)):

            for exp in range(i, positionOfEqualSign):
                if expression[i].isdigit():
                    print(expression[:i] + expression[i+1:])
```

For example if I run it as `solutions('1+2=2+1')` I should be getting only 2 possible solutions:

```
+2=2+1
1+=2+1
```

but I am getting:

```
+1=2+1
+1=2+1
+1=2+1
1+=2+1
```

Why is it outputting 4 different possible solutions, and 3 of them are the same? What am I doing wrong? 
P.S. Ignore the second part of the expression.

Comment: how does it become `+2=2+1` if you are  deleting a character one at a time up until the equal sign in a string?

Comment: You have two `for` loops, one of which has the wrong endpoint and the other of which you're ignoring. Perhaps you should review the code more carefully?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i forgot to mention, i am deleting, only integers in the string, not the operand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
def solutions(s):
    for i,c in enumerate(s):
        if c=='=':
            break
        elif c.isdigit() :
            print s[:i]+s[i+1:]
```

but I don't know what it is good for in a more general sense.

Comment: Or you could use a list comprehension:


    expr='1+2=2+1'

    print [expr[:i]+expr[i+1:] for i,c in enumerate(expr.split('=')[0]) if c.isdigit()]

Answer (score 0):

Ok i changed it a bit:

```
def solve(expression):
    positionOfEqualSign = expression.find("=")
    for i in range(0, len(expression)):

        if expression[i] == '=':
           break
        elif expression[i].isdigit():
           print(expression[:i] + expression[i+1:])
```